# Is there a way to find out the .nupkg target location for the msbuild pack target?

Tags: msbuild, nuget

If I'm using .csproj (not .nuspec) files and `msbuild /t:pack` to create nuget packages, is there a way to either specify where the .nupkg file should end up, or find out where msbuild is putting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory the nupkg will be put into can be controlled by an `PackageOutputPath` parameter, so you can call

```
msbuild /t:Pack /p:Configuration=Release /p:PackageOutputPath=..\mypkgs
```